# setAdapter and setDropDownViewResource are written in red by IDE

Tags: java, android, adapter

IDE say me "Cannot resolve symbol" in `setAdapter` and `setDropDownViewResource`, i don't know why:

```
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Thanks in advance everybody!

I post my code:

```
public class MyListFragment extends Fragment implements
        android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Planet> planetList;
    static PlanetAdapter plAdapter;
    private TextView txtName;
    private TextView txtEmail;
    private Button btnLogout;
    private Spinner spinner1;
    private Spinner spinner2;

    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private SessionManager session;
    BirraAdapter biAdapter;
    PlanetAdapter.PlanetHolder holder;
    private static Context context = null;
    private static FragmentActivity mInstance;

    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.mipmap.androtuto,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ok,
            /*R.drawable.image6,
            R.drawable.image7*/

    };
    String[] countryNames={"India","China","Australia","Portugle","America","New Zealand"};

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the custom_spinner_items for this fragment
        //super.onDestroy();

        SharedPreferences settings = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
        context = getActivity();
        mInstance = getActivity();
        txtName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtEmail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.numero_telefonico);
        btnLogout = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

        // SqLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(context.getApplicationContext());


        // session manager
        session = new SessionManager(context.getApplicationContext());
/*

        if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
            logoutUser();
        }
*/

        // Fetching user details from SQLite
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

        String name = user.get("name");
        //String email = user.get("email");
//      String email = user.get("email");
        String email = user.get("numero_telefonico");


        // Displaying the user details on the screen
        System.out.println(name + email);

        txtName.setText(name);
        txtEmail.setText(email);
    /*  Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showResult(v);


            }
        });*/
        //return inflater.inflate(R.custom_spinner_items.fragment_list2, container, false);
        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                logoutUser();
            }
        });

    /*  List<String> spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
        spinnerArray.add("item1");
        spinnerArray.add("item2");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Spinner sItems = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.simpleSpinner);
        sItems.setAdapter(adapter);*/
        return rootView;
    }
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.simpleSpinner);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getContext(),
            R.array.country_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    //adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share your project settings and the errors from the output of the IDE ( Errors in Eclipse for example ). What classes are you importing? The code sample is not complete

Comment: in what sense "what classes are you importing"?

Comment: you import classes at the top of your class definition, please add it to the code sample. make the code sample complete so it can be runnable. and what IDE do you use?

Answer (score 4):

It is because those lines should be inside some method. You should instead write it like:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.simpleSpinner);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getContext(),
        R.array.country_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

     spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```